# How to display GREEK Characters in JDeveloper's Logging Console

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.1.4.0 and i want to display Greek characters in the **Debugging: IntegratedWebLogicServer - Log** console.

When i try to do a System.out.print statement Greek characters display as question marks.

I have changed the Preferences>Environment>Encoding to UTF-8 but no luck.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Tried, still displays them in ??????? . By changing that option i also got encoding issues displaying Greek characters coming from property files - Reverted back to UTF-8

Comment: What do you print ? is it constants from your code ? I'm not to familiar with jdev 11, but in jdev 10 you need to check the compiler encoding (in project properties)

Comment: I am developping a web application and there are three things i print. 1 Data sumbited by user in the front html pages, 2 Data from the database, 3 Characters from property files. Everything is working ok with character encoding set to UTF-8 (environment encoding and compiler encoding). I just have the problem that i cannot display greek characters in the weblogic log console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution for the problem (at least it worked for me with JDev 12.1.2.0 but I believe it should work on 11.x as well):

Add the following line in the jdk.conf (JDEV_HOME/jdeveloper/ide/bin) and restart JDeveloper:

```
AddVMOption  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need setup UTF-8 encoding for compiler.

In your **Project's properties** dialog goto **Compiler** and set there desired character encoding.

Comment: Compiler settings setted up exactly in project's properties? Not in default project's properties? I had the same issue with cyrrilic characters and resolved it changing compiler encoding.

Comment: yes it is already UTF-8 as i told you before. If i change that to anything else then my jsp's dont show any greek characters. They just show symbols

Comment: Strange behavior. That was my steps: Convert source code into utf-8. Setted up environment encoding as utf-8. Changed compiler character encoding as utf-8 both inside ViewController and Model projects. Clean  all. Rebuild.

Comment: Check if it is also required to set outputstream's encoding, for runtmie!

Answer (score 0):

Got letters ???ed  for Cyrillics in log output . Following @Ravinder Reddy 's advice settled it so:

**Run -> Choose active Run config -> Manage Run Configurations...-> Manage ...**
Then in popup indicate a config and click on pencil icon to edit

[image]

And then in java options put in  **-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**

[image]

And now they appear encoded correctly
e.g. for a gear icon as a character:

```
String gear_= new String( "\u2699".getBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
settingsButton = new JButton(gear_);
```