# Issue with Translation API in Java

Tags: java, jdeveloper

i am trying to translate from english into Arabic using `translate.googleapis.com`.

it works well with all letters except one letter it always show letter 'ف' as '�?'
any suggestions ?

```
private static String callUrlAndParseResult(String langFrom, String langTo, String word) throws Exception {
    String url =
        "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?" + "client=gtx&" + "sl=" + langFrom + "&tl=" +
        langTo + "&dt=t&q=" + URLEncoder.encode(word, "UTF-8");
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    URLConnection con = obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return parseResult(response.toString());
}

private static String parseResult(String inputJson) throws Exception {
    /*
   * inputJson for word 'hello' translated to language Hindi from English-
   * [[["??????","hello",,,1]],,"en"]
   * We have to get '?????? ' from this json.
   */

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(inputJson);
    JSONArray jsonArray2 = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(0);
    JSONArray jsonArray3 = (JSONArray) jsonArray2.get(0);

    return jsonArray3.get(0).toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String word = callUrlAndParseResult("en", "ar", "phone");
        System.out.println(new String(word.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

i am using jdeveloper 12cR2

Comment: Probably your console doesn't support it, try to write it to a file and open with a good texteditor.

Comment: Maybe you should use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-

Comment: I think it's the same problem than this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698709/how-to-display-greek-characters-in-jdevelopers-logging-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that whenever you use `Reader`, there will be conversions between charsets. If you do not specify your charset, it will use the system default charset to encode the incoming byte stream, and you would get into trouble if the incoming byte stream is actually not in the same charset with your system.

Therefore, it is advised to specific the charset when using `Reader`.

So your code should like below.

```
private static String callUrlAndParseResult(String langFrom, String langTo, String word) throws Exception {
    String url =
        "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?" + "client=gtx&" + "sl=" + langFrom + "&tl=" +
        langTo + "&dt=t&q=" + URLEncoder.encode(word, "UTF-8");
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    URLConnection con = obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return parseResult(response.toString());
}

private static String parseResult(String inputJson) throws Exception {
    /*
   * inputJson for word 'hello' translated to language Hindi from English-
   * [[["??????","hello",,,1]],,"en"]
   * We have to get '?????? ' from this json.
   */

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(inputJson);
    JSONArray jsonArray2 = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(0);
    JSONArray jsonArray3 = (JSONArray) jsonArray2.get(0);

    return jsonArray3.get(0).toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String word = callUrlAndParseResult("en", "ar", "phone");
        System.out.println(word);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```